# Strange 404 URL requests on my site

Tags: web-hosting, django, http-status-code-404

I recently launched a Django powered site and I have 404 error reporting on. I've been getting some strange URL requests, one every couple of days.

/renewPwd.php/ 
/index.php/ 
/mobile/ 
/m/ 
/admininstrator/

I find some of them very strange since I don't have a PHP site or mobile site.

Does anybody know what's causing this and more importantly, should I be worried/do something about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this isn't you, then it must be somebody else...

It's common for the web to have Bots, Spiders and Crawlers. Check your log files for the IP to see where the request is coming from. These crawlers usually just use "common" URL paths in the hope that you're using them.

If they are just crawling you, then that is not an immediate security threat. But if you have a lot of content (and big images) and they are crawling that, it could be very annoying and could cost you more bandwidth.

There are simple ways to limit these crawlers. And for better security, I suggest you implement a Web Application Firewall. There are a lot of paid services but you could simply use Mod_Security.